# Windows 2003 service: disable message "the memory could not be written"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-service

I have a Windows service which throws a memory related error and then restarts. It's basically an Apache service running PHP.

Besides trying to fix the error, which is something I'm working on, I need to know how to disable this annoying message:

> The instruction at 0xmmmmmmmm referenced memory at 0xnnnnnnnn. The memory could not be written.

The problem is that the service won't restart until someone clicks the "Accept" button on the server.

In this case, service restarts are tolerable, what is not tolerable is having the service down until someone clicks the button. This message appears on the login screen (user is not logged in).

I need to ensure that the service will restart on error without any human interaction with the server.

Comment: I don't think that's normal behaviour.  It may be the runtime library doing it; do you know what language the service was written in?

Comment: It's an apache service running php.

Answer (score 0):

The application needs to handle all windows errors for services and the service should stop.  If a service properly throws an error, error recovery can kick in and restart the service (or perform some task to resolve the issue)

Comment: Thanks for the info. So this means that Windows **Server** expects someone to be next to the machine and click "ok". Even if the service is completely at fault I would expect more of server OS.

Comment: *So this means that Windows Server expects someone to be next to the machine and click "ok"* -- No. It it means that the application/service was written by a chimpanzee who can't write proper error handling code.

Comment: @jbm, if the server was at fault, it would generate an appcrash, ( and likely a bluescreen)the error you have is specific to code

Comment: I'm not saying that the OS is at fault at code level, but at design level. What purpose serves a sign with an "Ok" button that no one is ever going to see? Wouldn't it be better if I as an admin could choose what to do, like just logging to disk and restarting the service? That would actually be useful.

Comment: @Jbm  Right, but it's the coder who wrote the application/service who decided to pop up a dialogue requiring user interaction instead of having the service log an error and restart (or fail or try to continue).  Windows is just doing what the code tells it to do.  What application/service is this?  Maybe if you share that, someone who's used this app/service will be able to share a solution.

Comment: It's an apache service running php. Probably some bad combination of php + a faulty extension. Anyway, that would probably belong to stackoverflow, not here. I just wanted to know if there was something I could do from outside when services go bad, and like it seems there's nothing I can do, I'll probably accept this answer.